# How to simulate masks when doing draw operation in HTML canvas?

Tags: html, canvas, mask

I have two images loaded in 2 canvases / CanvasRenderingContext2Ds in HTML.

I need to perform drawing operations on the first image (practically erase part of the image).

However I would like to "block" certain areas, e.g. whenever a HTML drawing operation is done 
on that blocked part, the operation must not be done (e.g. somewhat a destination-in composite operation).

To define what areas are blocked, the second image is used. The image is practically a "mask" 
of the first image. It means that there are areas/blobs on the second images which are cleared out
(e.g. transparent), otherwise the rest of the image is pure, solid white.

So the purpose would be whenever a drawing operation is "within" (either fully or partially)
in any of the transparent blobs in the second image, the drawing operation would not be done
(or would be done partially, depending how the given operation overlaps with the given blob 
on the second image).

Does anyone have any idea how that could be done?
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Well, it was easier then I thought.

I have transformed the second bitmap into an SVG, I have loaded that SVG's path[0].$.d into a Path2D and I have setup a clip() operation on every canvas operation.